# How To perform ETL operation on column level security in AWS glue job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have table in one database which has column level security applied to it, now I am performing some ETL operation on this table using glue job and writing this new table into another database after running glue job I am getting below error
Py4JjavaError:An error occurred while calling 065.getDynamicFrame.java.lang.reflect.Invocation Target Exception

so my question is it is possible to perform ETL operation on column level security if yes than how can I do that plz inform me and give some reference.

Advance Thanks & regards

Comment: What database are you referring to?

Comment: I am using aws athena

Comment: The table in which column level security is applied it is in aws redshift and I want to perform ETL operation on column level security and write table in aws athena

Comment: I don't think column level security is possible with Athena as it uses Glue catalog to store metadata and Glue only allows tabular level granular access

Comment: Dear sir, If you don't mind can I get your personal id so we can discuss this part with more details